# If statement, if string.count() = integer?

Tags: python, if-statement

I want this part of my code to count the number of spaces in a string, so far I have that covered, but now, I want the code to return 1 if there are no spaces in the string.

Code:

```
    string = string.count(" ")

    if string == 0:
        string = string.count(" ") + 1

    return string
```

I get the following error:

```
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'
```

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Simply *don't* assign the count (and `int`) back to the `string` variable. Using unique variables with *descriptive names* helps.

Comment: And as `string` is also the name of a module in the standard library, it's better not to use it as a variable name at all.

Comment: Replace `string = string.count(" ") + 1` by `string=1`. As for I understand, you are trying to increment the number of spaces by 1, when there are no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overreading your variable `string`, try using a new variable:

```
spaces = string.count(" ")

if spaces == 0:
    spaces = string.count(" ") + 1

return string
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `0` is considered to be `False` in a boolean context, I would use `or` here:

```
>>> string = "a b c"
>>> space_count = string.count(" ") or 1
>>> space_count
2
>>> string = "abc"
>>> space_count = string.count(" ") or 1
>>> space_count
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `string` as the name of a variable, because if you do that, you will be changing the type of `string` to an `int`. You can use a different variable:

```
n = string.count(" ")

if n == 0:
    n = string.count(" ") + 1
...
```

Remember that `count()` returns an `int`, so if you assign that integer result to `string`, it won't be a string anymore. Therefore you can't call the method `count()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

As the variable already declared as `string = string.count(" ")` the type of "string" at the moment is already an integer which is obviously has not 'count' attribute.

To fix your code, you just return `string = string + 1` instead of  `string = string.count(" ") + 1`

Also, as Christian mentioned, it is a good practice don't use some name may be confusing reader as the variable name.